# Duplicate keys are being made in my json file for storing ranks for discord.py bot

Tags: python, json, discord.py, bots

```
    @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    rankfile = os.path.join(here, 'databases/ranks.json')
    with open(rankfile, "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_users(users, message.author)
    exp = users[message.author.id]
    lvl = getLVL(exp)
    await add_exp(users, message.author)
    newlvl = getLVL(exp)
    if newlvl > lvl:
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
    with open(rankfile, "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    print(message.author.id)

async def update_users(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = 0
        
async def add_exp(users, user):
    users[user.id] += 5

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    exp = users[user.id]
    lvl = getLVL(exp)
    await channel.send(f"Congrats {user.mention}, you have leveled up to level {lvl}")
```

The first message sent produces this result in the ranks.json file:

```
{"ID_NUM_1": 5}
```

But after the second message this happens:

```
{"ID_NUM_1": 5, "ID_NUM_1": 5}
```

Then it stays like that no matter how many more messages I write (probably from the fact that it is no longer a valid dictionary)

I didn't even think it was possible to make duplicate keys without throwing an error, so how do I fix this? Thank you for you help.

Comment: It's not possible to create duplicate keys in a dictionary. There's no error, the assignment simply overwrites the value of the key.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the keys aren't really the same, maybe there are characters that look similar.

Comment: I am using vscode and it is even throwing an error saying duplicate key. It is the exact same characters.

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(users)`

Comment: `{183899242149052417: 5}
{'183899242149052417': 5, 183899242149052417: 5}
{'183899242149052417': 5, 183899242149052417: 5}`

That is the first, second, and third/infinite prints. I see now that the "duplicate" in not wrapped as a string. What does that even mean in this context? It is a string in the json file.

Comment: The first key is a string (it's surrounded by quotes), the second key is a number (no quotes). They're not duplicates.

Comment: These end up as duplicates in the JSON file because JSON requires keys to be strings. So it converts the numeric ID to a string. The JSON specification doesn't actually say that keys have to be unique, so this is valid JSON but not equivalent to the original dictionary.

Comment: Yeah it was still acting as a duplicate breaking the whole thing. Thanks @Barmar for asking me to do print(users) because I realized that for some reason the first one was an int??? So I just wrapped everything in str() and now it works perfect. Thanks for the help, I'll post the final code now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the user.id key was being set as an int for the first assignment, so I just wrapped every occurrence with str()

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    rankfile = os.path.join(here, 'databases/ranks.json')
    with open(rankfile, "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_users(users, message.author)
    exp = users[str(message.author.id)]
    lvl = getLVL(exp)
    await add_exp(users, message.author)
    newlvl = getLVL(exp)
    if newlvl > lvl:
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
    with open(rankfile, "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    print(users)

async def update_users(users, user):
    if not str(user.id) in users:
        users[str(user.id)] = 0

async def add_exp(users, user):
    users[str(user.id)] = users[str(user.id)] + 5

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    exp = users[str(user.id)]
    lvl = getLVL(exp)
    await channel.send(f"Congrats {user.mention}, you have leveled up to level {lvl}")
```